# Xelatex try lo load russian package if I use only ukrainian

Tags: xetex, chapters, babel

I was preparing several texts in xelatex in Russian, everything was fine. But today I needed to prepare in Ukrainian. Here is an example of a file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=85mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ukrainian,english]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}                         %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}


% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------
\setmainfont[StylisticSet=1]{Old Standard}% Основной шрифт текста
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\selectlanguage{ukrainian}
% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
\parindent=25pt %------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\tolerance=600

\hfuzz=0.2pt
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Розділ}
%\makeatother

\overfullrule=1mm
\begin{document}
\author{Богдан Тертишний}
\title{Зимові розповіді}

\chapter{}

Але щоб ви з....

Але ми цураємось....

\end{document}
```

At compilation I receive an error.

```
   ! Package babel Error: Unknown language `russian'. Either you have
```

It is unclear why xelatex loads the Russian language?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your aux file and recompiling? Your posted example works without error.

Comment: @AlanMunn, It's work. Thank's. But I get new error about command \chapter "Command \CYRR unavailable in encoding EU1."

Comment: Sorry but I don't get this error.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I created another question about this, because this is another error.

Comment: Ok. I've voted to close this question as a duplicate (it's a common `babel` error).