# \chapter command is wrong in ukrainian language (in russian works)

Tags: xetex, chapters, babel, ukrainian

This question is related to this [Xelatex try lo load russian package if I use only ukrainian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446595/xelatex-try-lo-load-russian-package-if-i-use-only-ukrainian)
In the case of the text in Russian everything is working, but it is necessary to indicate the Ukrainian language:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=85mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=ukrainian,english]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}                         %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}


% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------
\setmainfont[StylisticSet=1]{Old Standard}% Основной шрифт текста
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
\parindent=25pt %------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\tolerance=600

\hfuzz=0.2pt
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Розділ}
%\makeatother

\overfullrule=1mm
\begin{document}
\author{Богдан Тертишний}
\title{Зимові розповіді}

\chapter{}

Але щоб ви з....

Але ми цураємось....

\end{document}
```

but it is necessary to set the Ukrainian language:

```
\usepackage[main=ukrainian,english]{babel}
```

I get an error

```
{\Ukrainian \CYRR \cyro \cyrz \cyrd \cyrii \cyrl } 1.

! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRR unavailable in encoding EU1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.36 \chapter{}
```

But \chapter*{} instead \chapter{} works.

Babel-Ukrainian is installed.

Comment: Your system is not up-to-date. EU1 encoding has been replaced by TU for at least two years. Your example (with ukrainian as main language) compiles fine for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You mean OS? I use Fedora 28. That I need to update?

Comment: No. I mean your tex system.

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that you have an outdated tex system. I get similar errors with texlive 2016 and older.

With a current texlive 2018 your example compiles without errors:

[image]

Comment: How can I update TEX? sudo dnf update texlive* don't help.

Comment: Maybe I don't have some necessary package?

Comment: If you want a new texlive you probably will have to install a vanilla tex https://www.tug.org/texlive/. The tex systems in the linux distribuations are often outdated. And no you don't have a problem with missing packages, your packages are outdated. The babel support for xelatex has improved a lot in the last years. If you don't want to update you could try polyglossia instead of babel, it is older.

Comment: Of course, I can update the system. I can also wait until the update in the Linux repositories. But how was the question resolved in 2016?

Comment: You can get the new version of ukrainian.ldf from ctan https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/ukrainian and compare it with yours but I doubt that the information is usefull for your. At the end you will simply need a lot of newer files  to use babel with xelatex and ukrainian.

Comment: Thank, for help... I added \usepackage{xecyr} in preamble of document. That helped.